# Master/Sub item line number selection without a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm looking at a table called LINEITEM that lists several item numbers that are in a "Master/Component" arrangement. They call them kits. The idea being that a kit can contain any number of sub-items within it. Here's a quick example:

```
+----------+---------+---------+----------+-----------------+
| ORDER_NO | ITEM_ID | LINE_NO | KIT_FLAG | KIT_MASTER_LINE |
+----------+---------+---------+----------+-----------------+
|   858710 |   15291 |       1 | Y        |               0 |
|   858710 |     113 |       2 | K        |               1 |
|   858710 |   15279 |       3 | K        |               1 |
|   858710 |   15292 |       4 | K        |               1 |
|   858710 |   15321 |       5 | Y        |               0 |
|   858710 |     106 |       6 | K        |               5 |
|   858710 |   15563 |       7 | K        |               5 |
|   858710 |   15564 |       8 | K        |               5 |
|   858710 |   15296 |       9 | Y        |               0 |
|   858710 |     116 |      10 | K        |               9 |
|   858710 |   15479 |      11 | K        |               9 |
|   858710 |   15480 |      12 | K        |               9 |
+----------+---------+---------+----------+-----------------+
```

So order 858710 here has 3 kits. Line 1 is a kit "master" with a value 'Y' in KIT_FLAG, and Lines 2, 3, and 4 and all components inside of that kit with a value 'K'. Until we get to Line 5 where a second kit has been declared with Lines 6, 7, and 8 as it's components.

I need to show on each sub-item which line item is the "kit master" it belongs to.

My desired output is what is currently shown in the KIT_MASTER_LINE column. I can even accomplish this with a subquery:

```sql
SELECT ORDER_NO, ITEM_ID, LINE_NO, KIT_FLAG,
ISNULL((
    SELECT MAX(LINE_NO)
    FROM LINEITEM AS l2
    WHERE 
        l2.LINE_NO < li.LINE_NO
        AND li.KIT_FLAG = 'K'
        AND l2.KIT_FLAG = 'Y'
        AND l2.ORDER_NO = li.ORDER_NO
), 0) AS 'KIT_MASTER_LINE'
FROM LINEITEM li
ORDER BY LINE_NO
```

... However the execution plan is not short of abysmal and takes many many minutes scanning the large table.

I guess I'm curious if there is a better way to do this with window functions or similar. My otherwise blazing fast procedure and all it's optimizations are being destroyed by this one hangup of having to call the LINEITEM table twice.

I appreciate any insight.

Comment: Have you tried using outer apply instead of the subquery?

Comment: Can you post the execution plan? How about the table definitions, sample data and approximate row counts from your database.

Comment: There are about 20 more columns of predictable datatypes not being shown here that are selected. 
Execution Plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkLzGu9Y4

There's a fair shot the way I have it is as good as I've getting. Just something in my gut is screaming at me that this can be done with partitions.

Comment: what happens if you select based on just order number?  does it hit a key?  do you have an FK order number to the parent order table?

Comment: >what happens if you select based on just order number? It'll index scan a clustered index as expected since there is no outer where clause. >Does it hit a key? I don't follow you here. >Do you have an FK order number to the parent order table? Yeah. But I don't see how that helps me compute KIT_MASTER_LINE in a cleaner way than I am now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to chase down a solution by subtracting a rotating count from the line numbers. No correlated subquery and runs in seconds. Woo!

```sql
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN KIT_FLAG = 'K'
    THEN LINE_NO - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY KIT_FLAG, [Group] ORDER BY LINE_NO)
    ELSE 0
END AS 'KIT_MASTER_LINE'
FROM (
    SELECT ORDER_NO, ITEM_ID, LINE_NO, KIT_FLAG, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ORDER_NO, LINE_NO) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY KIT_FLAG ORDER BY ORDER_NO, LINE_NO) AS [Group]
    FROM LINEITEM
) AS [GroupTable]
ORDER BY ORDER_NO, LINE_NO
```